# Renaming file paths in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I need to execute several rename commands in a batch file and wish to store the batch file in a directory different from the directory storing the files that need to be renamed.

The following is a sample file

```
ren C:\test\old1.txt new1.txt 

ren C:\test\old2.txt new2.txt
```

I would ideally like to not have to copy the directory path everytime, since I might need to change the folder in which these files reside. I tried the following but it does not work. Probably I am not understanding the set command correctly.

```
set dirpath=C:\test\

ren %dirpath%old1.txt new1.txt 

ren %dirpath%old2.txt new2.txt
```

Any ideas how I might achieve this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your batch file seems to be correct. Just to make it play well with path names that contain embedded spaces, put double quotes around the name, like so:

```
set dirpath=C:\test\

ren "%dirpath%old.txt" new.txt
```

Obviously, if you have a hardcoded path (`C:\test\`) you shouldn't even need that. I tried your batch file locally and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I thought I had tried it with quotes, but must have done something wrong earlier.

Comment: I tried with absolute path and it doidn't work, but with a %variable% it works ! Thanks.
Sometimes Windows is like God, inapprehensible!